# Panning Off screen Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to be able to have an off screen canvas that would be greater than the onscreen canvas. The onscreen canvas would be my view port and I want to pan across the offscreen canvas. I want to click on a button and I want the viewport to move to a specific location of the offscreen canvas. Any idea how this would work? I am not making a game, just a big canvas with different things spread across.

Comment: I have answered this question myself, since no answers came from the community. Though it's not a complaint as to why no answer came but it is kinda annoying that my question was down voted without any comments or anything in sight. If there's something wrong or if I am breaking community guidelines, please post it so I am careful next time and rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by following steps from the following link:

[Panning and scrolling background images using the canvas element](http://bdadam.com/blog/panning-and-scrolling-background-images-using-the-canvas-element.html)

The tutorial talks about how to pan the background using an image. I replaced the image with an offscreen canvas. The offscreen canvas had thrice the width of the onscreen canvas.

```
offscreenContext.canvas.width = onscreenContext.canvas.width * 3;
offscreenContext.canvas.height = onscreenContext.canvas.height;
```

And when I had to move the screen around, I would keep the y Axis on 0 and calculate the new position for the x axis. This resulted the screen to pan from left to right.